# Training sklearn's SVC only yields 'positive'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

I am training a SVM with features obtained by a TfidfVectorizer. When testing the SVM by asking for a prediction, even feature vectors from entries which were used for training and were labelled as 'negative' will lead to 'positive' predictions. I have the feeling I am doing something basic wrong -- but I could not find out what it is from the documentation.

The code is more or less this:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.svm import SVC

data = load_data()                                  # a list of tuples, at position 0 is some text, at position 1 a label -- either 'positive' or 'negative'. Order is randomized.
vocab = {ch for entry in data for ch in entry[0]}   # the vocabulary


extractor = TfidfVectorizer(strip_accents='ascii', analyzer='char',
                            vocabulary=vocab, ngram_range=(1, 5), 
                            min_df=2, lowercase=False)
features, labels = extractor.fit_transform([entry[0] for entry in entries]), \
        [entry[1] for entry in entries]

clf = SVC()
clf.fit(features, labels)

for feature in features:
    print(clf.predict(feature))                      # testing on training data, half of the entries should be 'negative', but it always prints 'positive'
```

To give an impression of the data, two entries for each label:

> Positive
>   (0, 1)   0.15046358725
>   (0, 3)  0.431231348393
>   (0, 6)   0.126073691443
>   (0, 7)   0.053403320129
>   (0, 8)   0.172907188257
>   (0, 9)   0.176318488739
>   (0, 10)  0.0822510699681
>   (0, 11)  0.0750035434541
>   (0, 12)  0.245746908087
>   (0, 13)  0.070393261049
>   (0, 14)  0.217021712559
>   (0, 15)  0.0348732598324
>   (0, 17)  0.330453439288
>   (0, 18)  0.0801049801935
>   (0, 19)  0.121622267101
>   (0, 20)  0.155054690124
>   (0, 21)  0.105138945977
>   (0, 22)  0.104318311782
>   (0, 23)  0.142275533299
>   (0, 25)  0.114477206411
>   (0, 27)  0.160209505382
>   (0, 28)  0.129046778512
>   (0, 29)  0.0618410863719
>   (0, 30)  0.322325274638
>   (0, 31)  0.0341389957579
>   (0, 32)  0.310109380247
>   (0, 33)  0.112336563455
>   (0, 34)  0.0662718061209
>   (0, 35)  0.301680645638
>   (0, 36)  0.070241173501
>   (0, 37)  0.0490111226972
>   (0, 38)  0.0979593205615
>   (0, 39)  0.0596363664168
>
> Positive
>   (0, 1)   0.117625753539
>   (0, 3)  0.393303780468
>   (0, 6)   0.0919882279376
>   (0, 7)   0.146119207993
>   (0, 8)   0.13517116455
>   (0, 9)   0.402027406205
>   (0, 10)  0.150033882678
>   (0, 12)  0.0896532112974
>   (0, 13)  0.0642020479106
>   (0, 17)  0.263715785035
>   (0, 18)  0.0487064026643
>   (0, 19)  0.0443701485229
>   (0, 21)  0.0479458938703
>   (0, 22)  0.190286659581
>   (0, 23)  0.0865080972171
>   (0, 24)  0.0593888745322
>   (0, 25)  0.156613097216
>   (0, 27)  0.37573403916
>   (0, 28)  0.0941575069348
>   (0, 29)  0.112804104567
>   (0, 30)  0.0734940476429
>   (0, 32)  0.0404049579898
>   (0, 33)  0.0512281809479
>   (0, 34)  0.0604430823106
>   (0, 35)  0.432374318506
>   (0, 36)  0.128126673468
>   (0, 38)  0.238249661904
>   (0, 39)  0.0543912413894
>
> Negative
>   (0, 1)   0.0577944775799
>   (0, 3)  0.421629123125
>   (0, 6)   0.101694787822
>   (0, 7)   0.143589019178
>   (0, 8)   0.232453464603
>   (0, 9)   0.26666950341
>   (0, 10)  0.0368589769154
>   (0, 12)  0.165188968649
>   (0, 13)  0.0946354953804
>   (0, 14)  0.0364700345073
>   (0, 15)  0.0468830136663
>   (0, 17)  0.416489951344
>   (0, 18)  0.0717945095888
>   (0, 19)  0.098104136602
>   (0, 20)  0.0893369449956
>   (0, 21)  0.106010249646
>   (0, 22)  0.105182814722
>   (0, 23)  0.127515194624
>   (0, 24)  0.175081504231
>   (0, 25)  0.0384752992583
>   (0, 27)  0.123075952609
>   (0, 28)  0.20818593649
>   (0, 29)  0.0831380981142
>   (0, 30)  0.162498218497
>   (0, 32)  0.416905743313
>   (0, 33)  0.0755116766399
>   (0, 34)  0.0890946819135
>   (0, 35)  0.260726333632
>   (0, 36)  0.0629540209892
>   (0, 38)  0.0438982779995
>   (0, 39)  0.04008705517
>
> Negative
>   (0, 0)   0.140625053372
>   (0, 1)  0.185208158007
>   (0, 3) 0.434299020013
>   (0, 6)   0.124148980319
>   (0, 7)   0.0657350441611
>   (0, 8)   0.121619636365
>   (0, 9)   0.217033390727
>   (0, 10)  0.0337480747364
>   (0, 14)  0.100175877346
>   (0, 17)  0.406760691514
>   (0, 18)  0.131470088322
>   (0, 19)  0.179648270846
>   (0, 20)  0.136328159775
>   (0, 21)  0.0323543238518
>   (0, 22)  0.160508953733
>   (0, 23)  0.116752896535
>   (0, 24)  0.0400761509423
>   (0, 25)  0.105683937825
>   (0, 27)  0.140860408865
>   (0, 28)  0.0635383392931
>   (0, 29)  0.0761212324217
>   (0, 30)  0.297566697793
>   (0, 31)  0.0840445271321
>   (0, 32)  0.38171884737
>   (0, 33)  0.172846204642
>   (0, 34)  0.0815750798167
>   (0, 35)  0.212196443599
>   (0, 36)  0.11528138777
>   (0, 38)  0.0803865158889
>   (0, 39)  0.0734074055798

Comment: You are using a kernel-svm with rbf kernel without adjusting gamma or C. That rarely works. Also, rbf kernel SVMs are not really a good match for text data. Try LinearSVC.

Comment: That was exactly it. I only changed SVC to LinearSVC and the solutions are what one would expect now. It might be nice to change your comment to a post so that I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a kernel-svm with rbf kernel without adjusting gamma or C. That rarely works. Also, rbf kernel SVMs are not really a good match for text data. Try LinearSVC.